# How can I save a reference to a generic type in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a message queue that uses JSON to save messages, and a set of message receivers that are keyed by type. I have these methods to add and remove items from the queue:

```
public void AddToQueue<T>(T message)
{
    var msg = JObject.FromObject(message);

    msg["_type"] = typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName;

    notificationQueue.PushBack(msg.ToString());
}

public void DispatchFromQueue()
{
    var notification = notificationQueue.PopFront();
    if(notification != null)
    {
        var jobj = JObject.Parse(notification);
        var type = Type.GetType(jobj["_type"].Value<string>());

        var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(notification, type);

        // handle message
    }
}
```

I believe these would work for ordinary types, like `string` or `MyCustomClass`. However, I believe it will fail for generic types, such as `MyGenericClass<T>`, or crazy cases like `ClassA<ClassB<ClassC>>`.

Is there a standard way of getting/resolving type names that have the generic parameters built in? If not, how could I do this manually?

Comment: Does not `.GetType` gets the `Type` that represents a type, that is, the Type's type?

Comment: It does, but I need to serialize it, and then deserialize it later

Comment: The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) for that overload states the typeName is **"The assembly-qualified name of the type to get."** So, in principle, there shouldn't be any problem. BTW, I didn't know that overload, I guess you learn something new everyday :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of belive it's better to test, in this case that won't take much time:

```
var message = new Tuple<string, Tuple<int, HashSet<double>>>("test", new Tuple<int, HashSet<double>>(2, new HashSet<double>() { 2d, 3d }));            
var msg = JObject.FromObject(message);
msg["_type"] = message.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
var notification = msg.ToString();
var parsed = JObject.Parse(notification);
var type = Type.GetType(parsed["_type"].Value<string>());
var back = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(notification, type);
// all is fine here
```

That's because type name for generic type already contains all necessary info:

```
System.Tuple`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Tuple`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],
[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[System.Double, mscorlib,     
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], System.Core, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib,
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

Note that your approach will not work if message is dictionary (either will fail or deserialize incorrectly) because of the way JSON.NET handles types that implement `IDictionary`.

Comment: Oh, shoot, I based my beliefs from reading the page on MSDN, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx . But, I read it wrong.